# Add votes to close on main page

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

On the main Questions page [here on SU](https://meta.superuser.com/questions), would it be a good idea to add a votes to close count, similar to the Votes and Answers count?

I think it would help close questions faster keeping SU cleaned up, what do you think?

Comment: Interesting idea. You can read some existing discussion of it [at Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35690/295684).

Answer (score 2):

There is [already a page like this](https://superuser.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=today) for moderators and users with 10k+ reputation like yourself. That provides an easy place to see all pending close votes, without cluttering the home page with unnecessary information.

The [close votes review queue](https://superuser.com/review/close/525193) is also another place to quickly see questions with pending close votes. If you want to contribute to keeping SU cleaned up quickly, spending some time going through the review queues is a great way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Review queue is ok but I could skim faster if close votes count were on the main page. I think I'm  beating a dead horse.

Comment: @Moab surely the close votes page in the 10k tools suffices for that? It literally lists every questions with close votes.